# Does keras support custom loss functions with y_true and y_pred different sizes?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've gotten this to (mostly) work, but I'm wondering if it's an unsupported use case?  Because it works with `model.fit(x,y,...)`, but when I used `model.fit(sequence_gen(),...)` it complains about the size, and some printouts reveal that it is assuming a `y_true` with the same dimensionality as `y_pred` (from the model).  My sequence generator makes outputs of identical shape to the `x,y` that work with a normal fit.

EDIT:

Here's an example:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.keras as keras

class seqGen(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self,N):
        self.N = N
        self.batches_per_epoch = 100
    def __len__(self):
        return self.batches_per_epoch
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        x = np.random.randn(self.N,200,3)
        y = 1.5*x
        return x,y
        
# y_true and y_pred: (None,200,3)
def myLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    yy = K.sum(K.batch_flatten(y_true),axis=-1,keepdims=1)
    print(y_true.shape)  # (None,200,3), seqGen (None,None)
    print(y_pred.shape)  # (None,1)
    print(yy.shape)      # (None,1)
    return K.mean(K.square(yy-y_pred))

inp = keras.Input(shape=(200,3))  # input (None,200,3)
F = keras.layers.Flatten()(inp)
outp = keras.layers.Dense(1)(F)   # output (None,1)
model = keras.Model(inp,outp)

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=myLoss)

# Single instance manually
x = np.random.randn(100,200,3)
y = 1.5*x
model.fit(x,y)  # <-- works

# With seqGen
model.fit(seqGen(100))  # <-- Error
```

Error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Can not squeeze dim[2], expected a dimension of 1, got 3
     [[node myLoss/remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze (defined at <ipython-input-20-f495648c7c5e>:38) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2362]
```

Comment: Yes it works. Make sure to declare the arguments of your loss function in the right order (it should be `def loss_func(y_true, y_pred):`)

Comment: Any thoughts on the seqGen version though?  In this case, I think TF has no way to know a priori what the output size is, so it assumes it's the same dimensionality as the network output.  Specifically, with an output of size (None,6) it assumed (None,None) (with the first being the batch).  In actuality, the loss function wanted (None,100,6).  This resulted in an error.

Comment: If you can produce a minimal reproducible example, that would help a lot. If you are using the `tf.data` API, try to set the shape of the tensors when building your data pipeline.

Comment: See edits above.

Comment: I would advise against using `tf.keras.utils.Sequence`: it's not really flexible, and I'm not really surprised it causes some pain in some edge cases.

Comment: Is there an alternative that does the same thing?  With simulated training, this approach allows multicore data generation and trains much faster than making batches one at a time and fitting them the standard way.

Comment: I would use the `tf.data.Dataset` API. You can maybe create a `tf.data.Dataset` directly from your `Sequence` object using `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`.